# GUI about AbtractButton

Tags: java, user-interface, jbutton

I am really new to GUI, got a little problem when I was trying to study it.
Ok here is my code.

```
public class Sample implements ActionListener{

public void go() {
    JButton button = new JButton("Click");
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().add(button);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(100,100);
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            button.setText("Hello");
        }
    });   
}
```

It keeps telling me that    The method `addActionListener(ActionListener)` in the type AbstractButton is not applicable for the arguments (`new ActionListener(){}`). I don't get it because I remember I did it before and it could work.
......

Answer (score 0):

I don't get an error but the action listener won't work because the action performed method of the ActionListener Interface needs to overriden.

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    // add the annotation below
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        button.setText("hello");
    }
});
```

And typically you would build the JFrame in the main method. Later they added an Invoke Later runner that when the class extends JFrame it would create the window in a more object oriented manner.

```
public class App extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    JFrame frame = new App();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public App(){
        JButton button = new JButton("Click");
        getContentPane().add(button);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(100,100);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                button.setText("hello");
            }
        });
    }
}
```